# React Router Nginx not working when navigate other than index route

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I setup simple route within my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import '../less/app.less';

import reducers from './reducers';

import App from './components/App';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome';

// const defaultSetting = settings;
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I already tried change my nginx config (sites-available):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

When I navigate to `admin.example.dev` using homestead I can properly show my index route. but when I navigate to admin.example.dev/login `it shows error index.js:24421 Warning: [react-router] Location "/login" did not match any routes`.

Any solution?

Comment: Could you try with `try_files $uri /index.html;`?

Comment: Try using `path="/login"`